# Database in cloud with REST API and ACL

Tags: javascript, database, rest

Is there a database, which can meet the following requirements

- hosted in cloud
- REST API
- support for different API keys with different access rights (especially Read-Only)
- free pricing program

I looking for database for Javascript application, without my own middle layer as provider between database and client application.

Comment: You want arbitrary machines on the internet to be able to route packets directly to your database machine? It's not that it's technically impossible, but it is vastly unwise. It's a good idea to stop and think what your application, your problem, what does it actually need?

Comment: If you allow Javascript to run arbitrary queries on a public database, that means any user can run arbitrary queries with the same privileges as your script. That's not typically what you want unless you really don't care about the stored data.

Comment: @deceze: Thats the reason, why I looking for database, where I can set different access rights for REST API. One for public site (ReadOnly) and second for my backend application.

Comment: Even "read-only" means that the user can read *any* data. For most applications that's a no-no. If you need to include logic so a user can only read *his own* data, you're pretty much looking at a middleware layer. Of course, all this may or may not apply at all to you. Have you looked at *any* databases with a REST API, like CouchDB?

Comment: @deceze: CouchDB is OK, but I could not find any provider, which can meet my requirements.

Comment: https://cloudant.com/for-developers/crud/ ? Just seen this one

Answer (score 1):

you have a lot of choices but still you can use free license for  development

you can try those

https://parse.com (its very good one and they have a lot of libraries  almost for programming language)

"http://couchdb.apache.org" (this is very good choice if you want to build local DB with JSON response )